# Repeat cached requests with RoboSpice?

Tags: android, caching, robospice

I'm using RoboSpice to fetch file listings from a server (cloud storage) for a file browser app. What currently happens is this:

1. User taps "folder A".
2. RoboSpice checks cache for "folder A", and checks if it is stale.
3. If it's found and is fresh, read it and update. If it's not found, fetch from server and update when finished.

What I want is this:

1. User taps "folder A".
2. RoboSpice checks cache for "folder A".
3. If it's found, read it and update. Then start fetching from server, and update when finished. If it's not found, fetch from server and update when finished.

Google Drive and Dropbox both do this. Is there a way to get this behavior with RoboSpice?

Comment: This guy was doing the same thing you expected. Yet he didn't use Robospice. Maybe it's useful at some points. http://blog.joanzapata.com/robust-architecture-for-an-android-app/

Comment: Thanks so much, this looks a lot better!

Answer (score 0):

I think RoboSpice it's better than the approach made in http://blog.joanzapata.com/robust-architecture-for-an-android-app/
It's more robust and it's out-of-the box highly documented solution ready for production apps.
You can do the cache check and loading first by using the mehod `getFromCache` from `SpiceManager`:
[http://stephanenicolas.github.io/robospice/site/latest/apidocs/com/octo/android/robospice/SpiceManager.html#getFromCache(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object, long, com.octo.android.robospice.request.listener.RequestListener](http://stephanenicolas.github.io/robospice/site/latest/apidocs/com/octo/android/robospice/SpiceManager.html#getFromCache(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object,%20long,%20com.octo.android.robospice.request.listener.RequestListener)))

Then in listener you can check, parse and update the data from cache and then make a new request with the `loadDataFromNetwork` method at `SpiceRequest`.